# Disable vouchers after refund

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

We have developed an payment module that works fine but when an customer asks for a refund and we refund that order the customer gets an voucher with that credit. We are not marking "Generate a voucher", just "Generate a credit slip".
We dont want to give vouchers because we are already (manually, outside prestashop) giving that money back.
How can we disable that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The whole logic around voucher generation after refund is inside

**controllers/admin/AdminOrdersController.php**

in the (huge) postProcess() method

Check for the part starting with :

```
if (Tools::isSubmit('generateDiscountRefund') && !count($this->errors) &&     
$amount > 0) {
```

You can just comment it , override or write your own logic...